In Javascript how is it possible to incorporate the result of a requested callback function in running code?
I come from PIC assembly-language programming where programs normally run continuously. I've now been learning Javascript for quite a while but have become a little blocked with the use of callback functions when they are given as a parameter of a call to an async function. I do realize that callbacks have been explained 'forever', but I have read about 10 books now cover to cover and get no clear answer.
First of all, most descriptions "brush under the carpet" how async functions are actually implemented in code. I see now that this is not normally part of Javascript but a part of the underlying host code (the browser - or even, perhaps, the OS that the  browser runs on). But Javascript must then have a mechanism to run functions that are not themselves part of Javascript language and the underlying host must have a mechanism for allowing Javascript to continue. I have never seen any code for this. I wonder how exactly does the host code put a specific block of Javascript in an event queue? This is all kept rather quiet it seems.
When it comes to the use of callbacks, I had the following assumption (by analogy), that turns out to be false.
I'm cooking and I need some salt, but I don't have any. I send out a friend to buy some salt, but I don't want to stop cooking. So my async function is goBuySomeSalt(nameOfShop, putItOnTable). I continue to cook and expect the salt to arrive later (and then to be putOnTable()). When the salt arrives I will use it in my cooking.
It seems though that Javascript does not allow this. Explanations of callbacks almost universally say that the callback will be called when the async function has finished. So I want to use my salt when my friend gets back. But I can't because I'm still cooking. There seems to be no way to use the salt until I've finished cooking because my friend is waiting right at the back of the event queue and they will only put the salt on the table when I've finished what I'm doing.
Thus my request for salt was essentially useless.
Am I missing something? Can I "poll" during my cooking for the salt? Can I be informed when the salt has arrived?  (Please note; I've already read about promises etc.)
Below is my code to illustrate this:
function a(){
  setTimeout(d, 1000);
  console.log ("Please fetch some salt!")
}

function d(){ console.log("Here's your salt - sorry I'm too late");}

a();

for (let i = 0; i < 4000000000; i++) {
  if (i%1000000000 == 0) { console.log ("Cooking");}
}

console.log ("finished cooking - but used no salt!!")


The order of the output is:
"Please fetch some salt!"
"Cooking"
"Cooking"
"Cooking"
"Cooking"
"finished cooking - but used no salt!!"
"Here's your salt - sorry I'm too late"

Javascript is single-threaded.  It can only do one thing at a time.  In this case, it's cooking.   When that's finished, you get your setTimeout event/callback fire.  The solution would be to move your cooking procedure to also be async.

As it states in this SO answer:  Embrace the asynchronous nature of JavaScript!

The reason you're finding it difficult to find an online solution is because we try not have long running processes - as js is single-threaded it means it can't do anything else while it's "stuck" in your for loop - and that includes updating the UI - so your app isn't actually "cooking" - it's "busy" - this would become more obvious if you tried to eg update a div instead of console.log - this div would not be updated periodically with the "cooking" statements - they would all come at once at the end and then be overwritten by finished.

"Javascript must then have a mechanism to run functions that are not themselves part of Javascript" it does not. There are bindings provided by the host environment. From within JavaScript, you're "calling a JavaScript function". There is no separation of what is or isn't JS or outside code. The bindings for outside functions are within the purview of, say, Node.js (e.g., the fs module for file system access) or the browsers (e.g., fetch()). When writing JS code you don't have access to an "invoke_some_outside_code" function that will itself do what fs or fetch does.

Thanks for your informative comments. I think I'm now beginning to see the forest instead of individual trees. My initial picture of 'code' was main code interspersed with some callback functions that 'fire' occasionally. But my thought process should be reversed. That is, thinking of callback functions as essentially the main (or major part of the) code waiting to be fired. It might not be perfectly correct, but it's probably closer to what is happening than I initially thought. So .... new mindset .... EVENT DRIVEN CODE. Thanks again.

Funny, I would have though that among people who should have the less difficulties to learn callbacks would be PIC programmers. You say that PIC run constantly. But my hobbyist project with PIC never do (I power them with a small AA battery supposed to last month/years). They sleep, waiting for an interruption. Interruptions are quite common I think in this low-level programming world (yet, it doesn't change the difficulty you have here: in javascript those "interruption" don't "interrupt" the main thread. They run only if there is nothing else to do. While with PIC, even if PIC isn't in

standby mode, and is running a main code, that main code can still be interrupted)

@ chrslg .... yes, as you said, on the PIC I can use the values that come in from async events quite easily via interrupt handlers. If I wanted to do this in javascript code above I would only "cook" until I needed to use salt. Then I would have a humungous callback function that not only puts the salt on the table but continues cooking the rest of the meal for me - which is a bit odd if you think about it because the async function was ONLY required to fetch salt - not to cook. Of course I could break this it up with promises returning promises and chain them so that the logic is 'palatable'.

@SaK realistically, you'd use async/await which would handle all of that for you.

Since its single threaded, you can't do a traditional poll as you would in a multi-threaded environment without using a Web Worker
Web Worker setup
create a web worker as a blob or separate file:


console.log("Please fetch me some salt");

function d() {
    console.log("Here's your salt - sorry I'm too late");
}

// Worker script as a string
const workerScript = `
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    if (event.data === 'start') {
        c();
    }
};

function c() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 40000000000; i++) {
        if (i % 500000000 === 0) {
            postMessage("Cooking");
        }
    }
    postMessage("Finished cooking - but used no salt!!");
}`;

// Create a blob from the worker script
const blob = new Blob([workerScript], { type: 'application/javascript' });

// Create a URL for the blob
const workerUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// Create a new Worker using the Blob URL
const worker = new Worker(workerUrl);

// Send a message to start the worker process
worker.postMessage('start');

// Listen for messages from the worker
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
};

// Set timeout to simulate delayed function call
setTimeout(d, 400);




@Mike N ...Thanks for that. I haven't used Web Workers but your code does seem to allow me to use salt in my cooking after all. That's valuable insight for me should I get hooked on long running code and need to use async results in it.
